# cannot access sub folder of wordpress where I have installed another cms

Tags: wordpress, whmcs

I have installed whmcs in a wordpress site. When I try to access the admin mysite.com/whmcs/admin I am redirected to my site error page of wordpress. Would you please guide me on what I should write in .htaccess file or what should I do on mysite.com/whmcs ?

thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD work. I've used it before to have WordPress ignore a folder, but I cannot guarantee it will work with your CMS.

Find this section in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And add this line (replacing "foldername" with "whmcs"):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foldername|foldername/.*)$
```

So that the rewrite section looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foldername|foldername/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This should tell WordPress's URL rewriter to ignore the whmcs folder when it makes it's SEO-friendly URLs.